# Position of 'if' in statement

Tags: python, if-statement, difference

is there a difference between:

1. if x > 0: print x
2. print x if x > 0

Is the 2nd option preferred when the if statement is embedded in other code?
If not in what are the situations where one is preferred over the other?

Comment: second needs `else`, first doesn't need `else`. - ie. `print( x if x > 0 else -x )`

Comment: `print x if x > 0` is a syntax error. So it is certainly not preferred.

Answer (score 4):

## Answer (difference)

```
x = 5
if x>0:
  print(x)
```

will print: `5`

---

However,

```
print(x) if x>0
```

will give "invalid syntax".

---

Instead, you should use an `val1 if [conditional] else val2` clause:

```
x=5
print(x) if x>0 else print(x+1)
```

which will print: `5`

---

You could also do:

```
x=5
print(x if x>0 else x+1)
```

which will also print: `5`

## Conclusion

There is not preference of one over the other.
If you want have clear statements that are easy to find and follow, use the former.
Othewise, if you want to have less lines of code, use the latter.

Helpful link => [click here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html)!

Comment: this also works `print(x if x>0 else x+1)`

Comment: @furas true, although harder to read in my opinion, but I will add it as an additional item.